# How to make first row have specific name and image?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have application which populate `uitableview` with some properties received from an api call. So my question is how i can make first `cell` for example have name "Back" and some image and after that start populate other `cells` with properties received from api call? If someone can post some example it would be awesome.

Comment: for other cells do you have an array?

Comment: i have an array with some properties, and i want to show that properties inside the table after this specific cell. I know how to present them but don't know how to     make first one specific cell and after that start populating others cells with this properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CellId")
   switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel!.text = "back"
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "back.png")
        break
    default:
        cell.textLabel!.text =  array[indexPath.row - 1]
        break
    }
   retun cell
 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayCount + 1
}
```

Another solution using TableView header:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CellId")
        cell.textLabel!.text =  array[indexPath.row]
        retun cell
 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayCount
}


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      let  btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 60, height: 30))
      btn.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
      btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "BarCodeIcon.png"), for: .normal)
      btn.setTitle("Scan the Barcode", for: .normal)
      btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 42.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
      btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
      btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnTapped:", for: .touchUpInside)
    }

   @objc func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
   }
```

Comment: this overwrite my first cell value with this name "back", but  i need somehow to make values from my array start populating after this row. So basicly to start with indexPath. row = 1

Comment: Tried this but it won't show me first property. Results is: back, bbb, cc.

Comment: Try to use tableView header to replace the first row

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is not a first cell that can be scrolled out together with the other cells, but a header that stays at its place while the other cells scroll. If this is the case, you could use:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Section \(section)"
}
```

This creates a simple text header.

If you want to use a custom header, you had to define a header view:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView() // Here you had to use a view that you set up earlier
    return view
}
```

These headers can be created for every section of your table.

EDIT:

I implemented a simple tableView project, and added the code provided by Simke in his/her comments.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Title"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?  { 
        let vw = UIView() 
        vw.frame.size.height = 40 
        let btnBk = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: vw.frame.height)) 
        btnBk.backgroundColor = .blue 
        btnBk.setTitle("back", for: .normal) 
        btnBk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnAct), for: .touchUpInside) 
        vw.addSubview(btnBk) 
        return vw 
    } 

    @objc func btnAct(sender: UIButton!){ 
        print("a") 
    } 
}
```

Here, the button in the header view works, i.e. "a" is printed in the logs.

Comment: I need to be cell because i want to use didselectRowAt function to triger other function with different api call which will present diff values in this table.  Here is pic to illustrate my idea https://ibb.co/mR4kJ3c . I have two diff arrays. first one contain ["A", "B', "C", "D", "E"] and second one have store values depending on which cell you click, in this example if i choose cell B i will call specific func where i will get values from specific api.

Comment: And that i doing successfully but i need somehow to make possibility to go back and present again first array. And my idea was to do it with cell. Maybe there is better solution but i think this one is good also.

Comment: I find it strange that your function "back" can be scrolled out. Alternatively, you could setup a header view (as described in my answer) with a UIButton "back". Then the user would not have to scroll to the top in order to go back. However, if you have only a few cells so that scrolling is not necessary, this is not an argument.

Comment: Ah i see, yes its good idea to let user see back option while scrolling when i have a lot of rows.  Thank you.

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let vw = UIView()
            vw.frame.size.height = 40
            let btnBk = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: vw.frame.height))
            btnBk.backgroundColor = .blue
            btnBk.setTitle("back", for: .normal)
            btnBk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnAct), for: .touchUpInside)
            vw.addSubview(btnBk)
            return vw
    }
    @objc func btnAct(sender: UIButton!){
        print("a")
    }

Comment: i tried this but tapping on button not working. Do you know why?

Comment: I checked your code and it works for me, pls see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all divide the table view into 2 sections.

Section 0: Deque your custom required cell here.

Section 1: Deque your custom cell with data from API here.

Code example:

```
 extension ProjectDetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            //deque your cell you want to place before data from API
        case 1:
            //deque data from api here
        case default:
            break
        }
    }
```

**Note: Remember to reload table view after getting data from API**